# Jinja2 for item in list change to upper case

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to generate configuration using jinja2 and ansible. ansible read csv and set facts.

```
 {%- for item in facts_csv %}
  Hello {{ item.abc}}
 {% endfor %}
```

in the csv file "abc" has a value "mike". When i run the play book its generating "Hello mike". 
Now i want to print "Hello MIKE", without changing the CSV file values?

seems item.abc|upper and item.abc.upper() did not work. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The template works as expected

```
{%- for item in facts_csv %}
Hello {{ item.abc }}
{% endfor %}

{%- for item in facts_csv %}
Hello {{ item.abc|upper }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```
Hello mike
Hello MIKE
```